# Solana private-key to derive the path of BIP-44 standard

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter, wallet, javascript

Hi all I'm trying to develop my own deterministic key hierarchy with **BIP-44** , **BIP-39** and **BIP-32**.
The initial part of the project is done:

1. I generated the seed phrase thanks to BIP-39;
2. I created my master node and its private key thanks to BIP-32;
3. Now I'm trying to use branch paths to make my hierarchy work on other blockchains (I've already created addresses for **BTC**,**ETH**,**BNB** and ***SOL***).

If I run my code, importing a previously generated seed phrase, the addresses I generated earlier become visible again, so it works.
Unfortunately, however, it only works with the first three cryptocurrencies and not with ***Solana***.

I show you the code I used to generate the ***Solana*** key pair (I used the module tweetnacl-js on Node.js)

```
> const path = \m/44'/501'/0'/0/0`;
> const child =masterNode.derivePath(path);
> console.log("\n---------Solana---------\n" )  
> const keyPair =nacl.sign.keyPair.fromSecretKey(child.privateKey); 
> const publicKeySol = bs58.encode(keyPair.publicKey);
> bs58.encode(keyPair.secretKey); 
> console.log(${coin} address:${publicKeySol});
```

As you can see, i used the function ***fromSecretKey*** to derive the private key. I think this is the right one. From documentation of tweetnacl-js.
When I run the code, it (rightly) gives me this error: *"Error: bad secret key size"*

Since the private key that the master node generates is 32 bytes and is a Buffer, while the ***fromSecretKey*** function, from Doc , says: *"Returns a signing key pair with public key corresponding to the given 64-byte secret key. The secret key must have been generated by nacl.sign.keyPair or nacl.sign.keyPair.fromSeed."*

Is there a way to convert the child's private key to the correct format? Is there another library that allows you to do this that I don't know about? What do you think? I'm on the right track?

Thank you all in advance <3

Answer (score 0):

You're very close! Since you have the private key, you can derive the public key and create a normal keypair using `fromSeed` instead of `fromSecretKey`, as the docs say.

Here's the tweetnacl function in the docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tweetnacl#naclsignkeypairfromseedseed

Comment: but the seed I should pass to the function, can't be `child.privateKey` , or can I put it? Should i pass the general seed of the master node? I don't think this should be used as it is needed to have access to all accounts, am I wrong?

Comment: You should put `child.privateKey`. Unless I've misunderstood, the whole point is that you've derived the child seed from the master, and now you want a usable private key for the child, correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct, so i should use this one. Thank you.

Comment: Can i contact you in private for other questions for develop a crypto wallet non custodial?

Comment: Sorry, I think it's better to keep conversations out in the open, that way you can get answers from more people!